# Allow user to complete a form & attach document

Tags: attachments

I have a sharepoint, which is a repository of project document templates, which are blank.

The idea is that when people use one of the templates and fill it in for their project, they can submit it back to me and I may then choose to add it to sharepoint as a 'completed template example' for people to look at what i want from the submitter, is their name, their email, an overview of the document they are submitting and the completed document - and for that then to land in an email inbox

How do I do this?

Comment: And the result would be stored in a list? Then you can create a content type with these site columns, add the content type to the list and remove the default one. No coding required

Comment: @BennySkogberg

I want the information to be emailed to a specific email address, not stored on the sharepoint, or stored somewhere on sharepoint that only certain users have visibility of

And i need the user to be able to attach a document, word, powerpoint etc

Comment: Oh! Then you can use a workflow which allows you to send e-mail to a specific user. But why do you want to do this in SharePoint? Seems like an odd solution. Why not use an [Outlook Template](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/send-an-email-message-based-on-a-template-56c645fc-1b25-4059-808b-55ee72b6bc2d)?

Comment: @BennySkogberg

Okay, let me try and explain.

I have a sharepoint, which is a repository of project document templates, which are blank.  The idea is that when people use one of the templates and fill it in for their project, they can submit it back to me and i may then choose to add it to sharepoint as a 'completed template example' for people to look at

what i want from the submitter, is their name, their email, an overview of the document they are submitting and the completed document - and for that then to land in an email inbox

Comment: Nice! Please edit your question so we get the scope :)